# Keeping DRY controllers and views for multiple versions of the same model type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, dry

I would like to use the same model for 3 distinct groups of tags that can be assigned to a page.  I would like use the same Controller and Views for all 3 groups.

**Models**

I was planning to use TPH as this is the default. Is there a reason to do otherwise?

```
public class Tag 
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string TagText {get;set;}
    public int PageAssignments {get;set;}
}

public class TagType1: Tag
{}
public class TagType2: Tag
{}
public class TagType3: Tag
{}

public class Page 
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Tag> TagsOfType1 {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Tag> TagsOfType2 {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Tag> TagsOfType3 {get;set;}
}
```

**Controllers**

I was hoping to use a `BaseController` to perform the heavy lifting.

```
// select and display
public virtual IQueryable<Tag> TagsOfTypeAsQueryable { get; set; }

// add, edit and delete
public virtual DbSet<Tag> TagsOfTypeAsDbSet { get; set;  }


public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Tag> allTags = TagsOfTypeAsQueryable.ToList();
    return View(allTags);
}
public ActionResult Add(Tag tag)
{
    TagsOfTypeAsDbSet.Add(tag);
}
.... more actions that can be used for all 3 types of tag....
```

And derive 3 controllers that would provide the right IQueryable or DbSet to operate on.

```
public override DbSet TagsOfTypeAsDbSet 
{
    get
    {
        return DB.TagsOfType1;
    }
}

public override IQueryable TagsOfTypeAsQueryable 
{
    get
    {
        return DB.TagsOfType1.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

**...But Problems...**

I am not allowed 3 DbSets of the same type:

```
public DbSet<Tag> TagsOfType1 {get;set;}
public DbSet<Tag> TagsOfType2 {get;set;}
public DbSet<Tag> TagsOfType3 {get;set;}
```

But if I create 3 DbSets, like this, I cannot use a BaseController to share actions between the 3 types:

```
public DbSet<TagType1> TagsOfType1 {get;set;}
public DbSet<TagType2> TagsOfType2 {get;set;}
public DbSet<TagType3> TagsOfType3 {get;set;}
```

---

*Is there a way I can approach this that will allow me to use the same controller for all 3 tag types?*

Comment: only base class definition required in dbcontext class and you have to choose which aproach to apply for database creation. tpc-tpt or tph

Comment: If I only have a base class definition in dbContext, how do I add / edit / select tags in of a particular type the controller?  Sorry if that's a daft question, I just can't work it out.

Comment: you can do that using ofType<derivedclass>() extension method

Comment: Cool, thank you. I'll play around with that.

Comment: As somebody who has more experience than I do... would you say I'm on the right track with the approach above?